# Align all colums of all TableRows

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a Layout like this:

[image]

I have a `TableLayout` in my Activity layout:

```
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="1" >
        </TableLayout>
```

then I inflate a `TableRow` with this Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tablerow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/value"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="value" />

</TableRow>
```

And add it to the `TableLayout`. I tried setting `stretchColumns` to 0 or 1, used different `layout_width` values, to no avail. 
I need all the first columns of all the `TableRows` to be as broad as the broadest TextView.

Comment: try wrap_content for width and no weight on your TextView's in the TableRow

Comment: Yes, that works. I thought I had tried already. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too! may be the graphical layout is not proper, but when I ran the app on 6 devices...it was working good for all of them ! (including samsung tab!!..)so just run and see it .

Comment: I ran this on devices, the width of the first column always wraps the TextView and they all differ. Thanks for the input though.